# CardView inside ConstraintLayout overlapping edge

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to have two CardViews next to each other, but as the ImageView inside of them is bigger than the CardView, it overlaps on the edges. The margin on the sides should be equal to the other cards.

```xml
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/card_instagram"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_register">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_facebook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_facebook" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_instagram"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_facebook"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_register">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_instagram"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_instagram" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

How do i keep the margin to the edges and stop the CardViews from overlapping? The images should still fill the entire CardView, regardless of some part of the image not visible.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set width of `CardView`s `wrap_content`. That's why it's taken width as it's needed. Give `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`. It will work fine then.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_facebook"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/card_instagram"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_register">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_facebook" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_instagram"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_facebook"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_register">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_instagram"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_instagram" />
    </LinearLayout>
    
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why 0dp works? Wouldn't that mean that the CardView is invisible as it has zero width?

Comment: In `ConstraintLayout` if any child has both constraint on any axis (like end and start, or top and bottom) then 0dp means take full length. Your card view has constraint for both end and start. That's why using 0dp solved your problem.